# Can't debug C++ in VS code with gdb

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-code, gdb, mingw

I'm trying debugging C++ in Visual Studio Code, but here is something wrong.
The debug status keeps scrolling, but no console shows. If I stop debug (shift+ F5), I won't be able to debug again. Whether click the green triangle or F5, nothing happens. [Debug screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lbWq1.png)

Building is OK. It's just the debug problem.
MinGW has been added to PATH. I can use g++ or gdb in CMD.

My environments:

- OS: Windows10 1803
- Visual Studio Code: 1.24.0
- C/C++ extension: 0.17.4
- MinGW_w64: x86_64-8.1.0-release-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0

Here are my configs:

c_cpp_properties.json:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": [
                "C:/MinGW/include",
                "C:/MinGW/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include",
                "C:/MinGW/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include",
                "C:/MinGW/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++",
                "C:/MinGW/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/backward",
                "C:/MinGW/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/tr1",
                "C:/MinGW/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/x86_64-w64-mingw32",
                "${workspaceFolder}"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE"
            ],
            "compilerPath": "C:/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe",
            "intelliSenseMode": "clang-x64",
            "browse": {
                "path": [
                    "C:/MinGW/include",
                    "C:/MinGW/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include",
                    "C:/MinGW/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include",
                    "C:/MinGW/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++",
                    "C:/MinGW/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/backward",
                    "C:/MinGW/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/tr1",
                    "C:/MinGW/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/x86_64-w64-mingw32",
                    "${workspaceFolder}"
                ],
                "limitSymbolsToIncludedHeaders": true,
                "databaseFilename": ""
            },
            "cStandard": "c11",
            "cppStandard": "c++17"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

launch.json:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "(gdb) Launch",
            "preLaunchTask": "build",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": true,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "miDebuggerPath": "C:/MinGW/bin/gdb.exe",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ]
        }]
}
```

tasks.json

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "build",
            "type": "shell",
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "presentation": {
                "echo": true,
                "reveal": "always",
                "focus": false,
                "panel": "shared"
            },
            "windows": {
                "command": "g++",
                "args": [
                    "-g",
                    "\"${file}\"",
                    "--std=c++11",
                    "-o",
                    "\"${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe\""
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

settings.json

```
{
    "files.associations": {
        "iostream": "cpp",
        "ostream": "cpp",
        "cmath": "cpp",
        "array": "cpp",
        "chrono": "cpp",
        "functional": "cpp",
        "ratio": "cpp",
        "tuple": "cpp",
        "type_traits": "cpp",
        "utility": "cpp",
        "future": "cpp",
        "streambuf": "cpp",
        "sstream": "cpp",
        "initializer_list": "cpp",
        "valarray": "cpp"
    }
}
```

Comment: Your compiler path should be `"compilerPath": "C:/MinGW/bin/g++.exe"` in your c_cpp_properties.json

Comment: @HeheBoi Thanks. But still not work.

Comment: I was stuck on this problem for about 2 days, and this question worked for me. Thanks for sharing this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found out this is an encoding problem, and I solved it myself.

First, try gdb logging to find out whether you are having the same problem. 
Enable `"logging": { "engineLogging": true }` and if you see something like

```
1: (1992) ->&"\357\273\2771001-gdb-set target-async on\n"
1: (1993) ->&"Undefined command: "\357". Try "help".\n"
1: (1993) ->^error,msg="Undefined command: "\357". Try "help"."
```

Then you have the same problem.

To fix it, you need to disable **Unicode UTF-8 for worldwide language support** which is a beta feature since Windows10 1803 and is disabled by default. 
It is at **Control Panel** - **Clock and Region** - **Region** - **Administrative** - **Change system locate** (administrator authorization required) - **Beta: Use Unicode UTF-8 for worldwide language support** (system reboot needed).

Go to [why vscode just hang in there when start debugging with gdb.exe?](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/1527) at GitHub for more details.

Comment: Hi, where do you enable `"logging": { "engineLogging": true }`? I get unknown configuration setting